# Invalid timestamp format in Redshift COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue

I have tried almost every solution from SO but still same issue. I have a CSV file in S3 and a table in Redshift.

Table structure is as below:

```
like_id => inetger
p_id => integer
c_id => integer
date_added => timestamp (without time zone)
```

CSV file contains data as:

```
1|1234|9876|2012-08-12 03:30:00
...
...
1500|4545|87545|2019-01-15 08:10:00
```

When i run the COPY commnad in RedShift, it gives an error of `Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS]` , i have tried almost all time date format from RedShift but still stuck. COPY command is below:

```
copy likes from 's3://<myBucketPath>/like.csv'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=<IAM-Role-Here>'
delimiter '|' region 'us-west-2'
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS';
//timeformat 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'
//dateformat as 'auto'
//timeformat as 'auto'
```

**NOTE: I exported my table from MySQL in CSV format and `date_added` column's data type is `datetime`**

Comment: Can you show us your `COPY` command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sir, copy command is same as your's but i added the region also and also check by changing time and date formats.

Comment: What do you mean by "check by changing time and date formats"? Please edit your question and include your COPY command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sir, i have updated the question with copy command... pelase check.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Even if i use AWS GLUE's ETL job. it recognize my `date_added` column as `String` and in target table i choose the `timestamp` datatype . in result , job skip the date_added column and add NULL to date_added column in database table.

Comment: All I can say is that it worked fine for me without specifying a `TIMEFORMAT`.

Comment: can you tell me about glue ETL type casting or changing string to timestamp please?

Comment: Are you sure that the S3 path does not contain other files? Possibly with dates in wrong format?

Comment: Also one thing to try is to look into [stl_load_errors table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) - there you'll find the exact line that caused an error - that could give you a hint.

Comment: @botchniaque Sir, i have seen stl_load_errors... and error is in 1st line. my date format is YYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Comment: Maybe it's the header line ;)?

Comment: What did the first line look like, according to `stl_load_errors`?

Comment: @botchniaque sir, it is exactly looks like `1|1234|9876|2012-08-12 03:30:00`

Comment: Ok, but then have a look at @John Rotenstein's answer, and try to repeat it yourself and see whatever it fails.

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a CSV file containing:

```
1|1234|9876|2012-08-12 03:30:00
1500|4545|87545|2019-01-15 08:10:00
```

- Launched an Amazon Redshift cluster and created a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (like_id INT, p_id INT, c_id INT, date_added TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
```

- Loaded the data from Amazon S3 into Redshift with:

```
COPY foo
FROM 's3://my-bucket/bar/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-role'
```

- Selected the data:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo
```

The result was:

```
1     1234   9876  2012-08-12 03:30:00
1500  4545  87545  2019-01-15 08:10:00
```

**So, it seems to have loaded it by default without any need for particular settings.**

I know it is a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` because I can do this:

```sql
SELECT date_added + INTERVAL '15 minutes' FROM foo

2012-08-12 03:45:00
2019-01-15 08:25:00
```